# A cipher for beginners

Tags: cipher

I have been lurking on puzzling.se for quite a while, but I never joined the community before because by the time I figured out any puzzles, someone else had already answered them.  For that reason, I decided to put up this puzzle.  It is pretty straight forward, so it won't be much challenge for veterans, but hopefully it will encourage others like me to post a response.  So *playfair* high rep users and let a novice answer, because *community* is key.

> Gbol gmm rnxvrbce uc zybis gvndbuhf!

Comment: Whoops, I solved it and posted an answer before reading the full question. Now deleted my answer, under the "let a novice answer" stipulation :-) The best part is that high-rep users can see my deleted answer, so they'll get spoilers and have to let someone else go first! (Once a low-rep user has answered, I could maybe undelete mine in the hopes of this hitting HNQ and getting more rep for you and the accepted answerer ...)

Comment: I love the idea of beginners puzzles for the lurkers on the site!

Comment: I would suggest you guys make a tag for it. low-rep of beginner, something as a cue to high rep/experienced users to politely leave it alone :-)

Comment: Please link to a meta post on this if it gets started!

Comment: I started a question on the idea of a "beginner" tag [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/do-we-have-a-beginner-question-tag/6138#6138)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

well,

> using the playfair cipher with the key "community" (very subtle hinting, yes), we get:

> Have fun puzzling on stack exchange!

> [image]

Answer (score 10):

<sup>**Note:** I posted this answer before seeing the stipulation about letting low-rep users go first, and immediately deleted it once I realised. I've now undeleted it in the hopes of helping the question to hit HNQ and the asker / other answerer to get more rep. **Please upvote and accept [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56917/5373), even though mine was first.**</sup>

---

The solution is

> Have fun puzzling on stack exchange!

The cipher is

> [Playfair](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/playfair.php), with the key `community`.